# Show form as modal in a new thread

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, modal-dialog, .net-4.5

In vb.net, I have a winforms application which periodically launches a form to check several operations in a different thread of the main thread. I would like to show these forms in a "modal" way, so the thread access of the Main Form have to be locked.

Is it possible?

Is there another way to launch a form in a new thread without using Application.Run (new Form())…?

The code is as follows:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Friend NotInheritable Class Program

Private Sub New()
End Sub

<STAThread() _
Shared Sub Main()
    Application.EnableVisualStyles()
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false)

    threadFormCheckOperations.Start()

    Application.Run(New FormMain())

End Sub

Public Shared threadFormCheckOperations As New Thread(AddressOf launchThreadFrmCheckOperations)

Public Shared Sub launchThreadFrmCheckOperations()
    While(True)
         Dim threadForm As New Thread(AddressOf launchFrmCheckOperations)
         threadForm.Start()
         threadForm.Join() '---> Wait until thread is closed
         Thread.Sleep(60000)
     End While
End Sub

Public Shared Sub launchFrmCheckOperations()
    'I guess, here is where the code have to change… or is in the FormCheckOperations properties?
    Application.Run(New FormCheckOperations()
End Sub


End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can´t show a modal window from another thread, but you can show a window and make it always on top of other windows. This is because a modal window always needs an owner window... you probably know that a window has a handle, and such handles cannot be shared between threads. Since the main window handle belongs to main thread (usually the UI thread), showing a modal window from a separate thread is prohibited and will cause an exception.

Use something like this to show a new window...

```
Dim window As New FormCheckOperations()
window.Show()
```

Set the `TopMost`-property of the `Form` instance to true, to make the window stay always on top of others...

```
window.TopMost = True
```

You can also find an example for this in the MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost(v=vs.110).aspx

The `Run` method of the `Application` class is not the right way to show another form. It is there to start a message loop for the application; see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms157902(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but it doesn't solve my problem, since, if I open a form with `.Show()` method, it automatically closes. Using the property `.TopMost` could be a solution, the inconvenient is popup windows (i.e: messagebox) in extra form could not be shown since extra form always would be in top…. But the solution seems to be closer.

Comment: I think there´s some misconception in your application at all... I guess there´s some logic in the window class that executes when you show the window? It might be suitable to separate logic and UI and than have a single modal window that is shown, before any worker thread starts... each thread can than show data in the modal window (this requires some synchronization, of course, but would probably lead to cleaner and more stable application).

Answer (score 1):

You can make an application modal form from another thread by invoking to the Applications 'MainForm'.
The "MainForm" can be found using Application.OpenForms[0] if it is not directly accessible.

Something like this

```
    private DialogResult CallModalForm()
    {
        Form mainform = null;
        if (Application.OpenForms.Count > 0)
            mainform = Application.OpenForms[0];

        if(mainform != null && mainform.InvokeRequired)
            return (DialogResult) mainform.Invoke(new Func<DialogResult>(CallModalForm)) ;

        MyModalform form = new MyModalform ();
        form.TopMost = true;
        return form.ShowDialog();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to disable the main Window before opening the "modal"-Window and re-enable it after the modal is closed.

Comment: How could I do this in my current solution? (Launching the forms from `Application.Run()` method… Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can open a form using ShowDialog, which will stop execution of the code in the thread until the from is closed, but it won't show on top of any other forms.

I think to do what you want you will have to specify the owner form so that your modal form is on top. The issue is that you will get a `Cross-thread operation not valid` error if you try and do this on a separate thread:

```
frmModal.ShowDialog(frmMain) '< errors when run on a separate thread
```

So you will have to use a `Control.Invoke` like this:

```
Private Sub ShowModalForm()
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.BeginInvoke(New Action(AddressOf ShowModalForm))
    Else
        frmModal.ShowDialog(frmMain)
    End If
End Sub
```